# Unable to remove rows from table with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm unable to remove rows from dynamically created table. If a user selects a `option` then on change event will be invoked. Upon that event dynamically here I'm creating a table. If a user selects another `option` previous rows should be removed and new rows should be added to table.

```
<table id="tbl1"></table>
```

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#options').change(function() {
        $('#tbl1 tr').remove();
        if (this.value != "") {
            var tr = $('<tr>');

            //some code to add nu. rows dynamically

            $('<td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>').appendTo(tr);
            $('#tbl1').last().after(tr);
        }

        //end
```

What is my mistake?

Comment: pls post your code on jsfiddle.net

Comment: Is option is your select element's id ??

Comment: #options is select option id.

Comment: Option's value cannot be changed. Use select element to bind change event.

Comment: `$('#tbl1').last()` is pointless as there is only one. You probably meant to do `$('#tbl1 tr').last()` but `$('#tbl1').append(tr)` is a better option

Comment: sorry option value changed every time while i selects an item. But table rows are not removed.

Comment: If you can provide sample HTML that will make providing an *appropriate* solution a little easier :)

Comment: Then options is select element's id.

Comment: Basically you were appending the rows *after the table* with your existing code, so they are not found in the table to remove :)

Comment: Im removing all the divs from main div(#radiobuttons id) by calling $('#radiobuttons').remove(); after that im adding other divs like $('#radiobuttons').append("<div><input type='radio' name='radio' value='"+ugadisms[i]+"'/><label><span><span></span></span>"+ugadisms[i]+"</label></div>"); But freshly added divs are also removed. whats d problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this : You can make use of `append()` to add row at the last position in table.

```
$('#options').change(function() {
        $('#tbl1 tr').remove();
        if (this.value != "") {
            var tr = $('<tr>');

            //some code to add nu. rows dynamically

            $('<td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>').appendTo(tr);
            $('#tbl1').append(tr); //use append instead of after
        }

        //end
```

Comment: You do not need closing tags for single elements when creating HTML elements in jQuery.

Comment: `var tr = $('<tr/>');` would do.

Comment: @ LShetty: Even the `/` is not required by jQuery (but looks better I admit) :).